# Formatting HTML <a> Link Using PHP To Include Current URL and Pre-Defined Subject and Body Message

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I apologize if there's already an answer for this, but I have tried a few different options and they all fail.

First of all, I have a function that gets the current URL. It looks like this:

```
function non_working_url() {
echo 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

Secondly, by using a list of pre-defined `define();` where the website name, email and more are included.

I need to format a HTNL email link that includes the pre-defined email address, the current URL from the function, a pre-defined subject and a pre-defined body message.

How do I format this?

**Example of what I tried:**

```
<a href="mailto:'.ADMIN_EMAIL.'?Subject=.'non_working_url();'.?body='.URL_MESSAGE.'" target="_blank">Report URL</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the `echo`?

Comment: Whenever you run into a situation like this, break it down. Create a variable called $href (or w/e) and append the individual parts to it. As you do so, inspect it and make sure it's building correctly. This will stop you making mistakes with mixed single and double quotes, which is a very common problem. Also, you don't need to break your concatenation with `' . $something . '`, just simply wrap your PHP vars like so: `<a href="mailto:{$something}?Subject...` etc. Working with strings is a common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use return in function and http_build_query method

```
<?php

function non_working_url() 
{
    return 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}

define('URL_MESSAGE', 'This is very important message!');
define('ADMIN_EMAIL', 'admin@gmail.com');

$data = [
    'subject' => non_working_url(),
    'body' => URL_MESSAGE
];

$href = http_build_query($data);

echo '<a href="mailto:' . ADMIN_EMAIL . '?' . $href . '" target="_blank">Report URL</a>';
```

Comment: Since I am not an expert and I need to understand this, can I not define the Subject, Body Message etc?

Then just assign them all within an `<a href="` link, or is your version where you use what you need inside your data array?

Again, just trying to understand best practice. Thanks for your answer, I will try it.